# DataTable of Strings with a RowEditor will not save changes

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a need to display a list of Strings on a page, which a user will need to be able to add, edit, and delete entries.  I figured I would use a DataTable to accomplish this.

The page appears to work properly - values are displayed in the DataTable, rows are deleted when the Delete icon is clicked, and rows are added when the Add button is clicked.  **However, when engaging the RowEditor by clicking the pencil icon, changes are never reflected when clicking the checkmark; the value of the row just goes back to being blank**.

Here is a GIF showing the problem happening - https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGanX.jpg

I've copied the majority of the DataTable markup from other pages in my project, which all work properly.  The only difference I can see here is that this is a DataTable of Strings, not a complex object.  Does this affect the "input" facet of the RowEditor when the value of the InputText is just a simple String?

Here is the DataTable markup:

```
<h:form>
  <p:dataTable id="configTable" value="#{bean.configs}" var="config"
      editable="true" editMode="row" emptyMessage="No entries exist.">
    <p:column>
      <p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{config}" /></f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{config}" /></f:facet>
      </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
      <p:rowEditor />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
      <p:commandLink update="configTable" styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" process="@this" 
          actionListener="#{bean.removeEntry(config)}" />
    </p:column>
    <f:facet name="footer">
      <p:commandButton value="Add Entry" update="configTable" icon="ui-icon-plus" style="float:right;" process="@this" 
          actionListener="#{bean.addEntry()}" />
    </f:facet>
  </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Here is the relevant bean code:

```
private List<String> configs;

public List<String> getConfigs() {
  return this.configs;
}

public void setConfigs(List<String> configs) {
  this.configs = configs;
}

public void removeEntry(String entry) {
  this.configs.remove(entry);
}

public void addEntry() {
  this.configs.add("");
}
```

I am using PrimeFaces 5.3/JSF 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that when you press the check mark (to finish editing a row) JSF calls the setter method of whatever class your table rows are.

String class doesn't have a setter method, thus you will need to create a wrapper class with just one field (with getter and setter) and change your configs object to a List of `yourClass` objects.